# Выполнение кода до определённого момента

Tags: javascript, php

Имеется следующий код всплывающего окна:

```js
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div =
      this.parentElement;
    div.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      div.style.display =
        "none";
    }, 600);
  }
}
```

```css
.alert {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #c6e3f1;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz- border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px #b5cad2 solid;
}

.alert.success {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.alert.info {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.alert.warning {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <div class="alert">
    <span class="closebtn">×<br>
    Информация:<br>
    Текст...
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Код работает, при нажатии на крестик окно закрывается, но при обновлении страницы всплывающее окно вновь появляется.
Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на крестик один раз окно больше не появлялось, то есть оно отображалось на странице до тех пор пока не будет один раз нажат крестик чтобы его закрыть.
Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

При нажатии на крестик запоминайте это состояние либо в **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**, либо в **[Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies)**. При загрузке страницы проверяйте, если значение в `localStorage` есть, то окно надо скрыть тут же.  А лучше действовать наоборот. Если в `localStorage` ничего нет - показать окно, если есть - ничего не показывать

Comment: Подскажите а как это реализовать в коде?

Comment: Посмотрите как работает localStorage (там всего лишь три метода get, set и has)  в них невозможно не разобраться самому